# Invalid Command $n(0) in Tcl NS2

Tags: amazon-s3, tcl, ns2, knox-amazon-s3-client

```
for {set i 0} {$i < $num_nodes} {incr i} {
    set a($i) [new Agent/MessagePassing/Flooding]
    $n($i) attach  $a($i) $MESSAGE_PORT
    $a($i) set messages_seen {}
}
set Consumer n(0)
set Producer n(5)
$ns attach $a(1) $consumer
$ns attach $n(5) $producer
$ns connect $consumer $producer
```

where a comes from the agent node.Please tell me anyone why this gives error in agent a(0) in this line:

```
$ns attach $a(1) $consumer
```

Comment: What is `num_nodes` set to?

Comment: You are mixing the capitalization of Consumer/consumer and Producer/producer. Tcl variable names are case sensitive.

Comment: @DonalFellows num_nodes are total number of nodes wich is equal to 6

Comment: @glennjackman sorry, here we capitalized the words otherwise in code we have used the small letters 
Please tell me the solution Thanks

Comment: @glennjackman sorry, here we capitalized the words otherwise in code we have used the small letters .Please tell me the solution .

Comment: Including the actual error message would probably be useful here.